# Regex trim up to (but not including) last match

Tags: regex

I'm playing with using Regex to modify Twitter posts. I'm currently attempting to trim each tweet up to (but not including) the last occurrence of a retweet string (example: `RT @Sam:`). I'm already filtering my feed so that only tweets containing at least one retweet string are kept. The regex I'm using to do this is `RT @[A-Za-z0-9_]+:`.

So, my question is, simply, how can I trim (cut off) each string up to, but not including, the last occurrence of `RT @[A-Za-z0-9_]+:`?

So, for example:

> RT @Sam: Look what Susan said. RT @Susan: Hello!

should end up as:

> RT @Susan: Hello!

(In case it's helpful, I'm using Yahoo! Pipes for this experiment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex `(RT @(?!.*@).+:.+)` to find the match...

Negative lookahead `(?!.*@)` is a condition that says there is no `@` beyond this point.

Test it [here](http://regexr.com?31e8j).

Comment: Doesn't this say there's no `@` beyond this point, instead? Perhaps you mean a lookbehind?

Comment: @Arithmomaniac - It is **negative lookahead** - see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: I knew it was a negative lookahead, which is why I corrected your language. (I see you incorporated the fix.) I was suggesting that you could use a look-behind instead.

Comment: @Arithmomaniac - I am open to discussion - How whould you use lookbehind to find a match? You have to ensure there is no `@` infront, not back. Or am I missing something in your idea?

Comment: So, to my untrained eye, this seems to be working great. lol Here's my final code: http://regexr.com?31e8v I'm going to have to wait a while before I can actually see whether it's working in my pipe. Silly Twitter rate limiting. =P Thanks for the help!

Comment: btw, could you recommend some resources that could help me understand your solution?

Comment: @NathanArthur - My code above is for match, your is modification of my code to do replacement. Both are fine, as you can also assign the match to original string, which would be actually faster.

Comment: @NathanArthur - see second comment (above) there is a link to **regular-expressions.info** website...

Answer (score 2):

```
(.+)RT @.+:.+
```

The first capturing group will contain everything but the last RT @[Anything]:[Anything]

Comment: Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but your solution doesn't seem to work: http://regexr.com?31e8s

Comment: @NathanArthur: Since you asked to remove everything but the last entry, I gave you code to match everything but the last entry in the first capturing group (i.e. $1) To test this in regexr, go to the replace tab and put in `$1` as your replacement text. Note that regexr has a bug in it where you might need to put some other text in there with it to get it to work, like `xxx$1` then remove the `xxx`.

Comment: It looks fine to me. I think perhaps you aren't understanding what it does. It doesn't match the LAST ReTweet, but everything prior to it, in the first capturing group. The idea is that you could then remove that unwanted text from your value. Do you see how the value at the bottom of http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31f0j has everything but "RT @Susan: Hello!"?

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see now. Sorry 'bout that. +1

Comment: No worries. I guess it is a little bit of an odd way to implement it.